# Knockout MVC, bind model & add object to model

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

How can I add an item to a `List<ComplexObject>` with `KnockoutJS`?

This is my model:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is the client side script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

   // attempt:
   var newUser = [{ "Id": "13", "Name": "John" }];
</script>
```

How do I add `newUser` to the the `viewModel`?

Comment: Hi @Yustme, I updated my answer as I tested it in an mvc project and it output the json slightly different to my first answer. Please give that a go. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the following manner.

1. Create a User object
2. Create a mapping that maps your returned object to your new User object
3. Use a simple push to add a new User object

Please see full code below with comments

```
// 1. Create a User object
var User = function (Id, Name) {
    self = this;
    self.Id = Id;
    self.Name = Name;
}

// 2. Create a mapping
var mapping = {
    'Users': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new User(options.data.Id, options.data.Name);
        }
    }
}

var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);

// output to verify binding
console.log(viewModel);

// 3. Add the new User object
viewModel.Users.push(new User(2, "Jim"));

// output to verify added user
console.log(viewModel.Users());
```

**Update:**

Here is a jsfiddle with it working against a list:

http://jsfiddle.net/6qsjz/12/

**Update 2**

The null issue seems to be that you are not initialising the collection, add a constructor to your model like this:

```
 public MyModel()
 {
     Users = new List<User>();
 }
```

Comment: Yea forgot to add `Users` it's there now. If I run your code, i get this error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'push'`

Comment: Hi @Yustme, please re-copy the entire code that I have updated. I had to change quite a bit to get it working in an mvc project.

Comment: @Yustme I've added a js fiddle link with it working. Please accept answer if it works for you now.

Comment: I tried this approach too, but it still gives me an error `Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference`. The `Users` is null. But the `viewModel` does have data in the `_ko_mappings_`

Comment: I think you need to initialise the collection before it is sent back. Does it resemble the json that is in the working fiddle I supplied? It can be an empty initialised collection. If u add the json I will be able to see.

Comment: If you add a constructor to MyModel that initialises the collection you should be good.

Comment: I have your code placed in the `document.ready()` function. The `List<User>` is at that time empty (null). And then I tried to add a user (hard coded) to see if that works. Then I can move with user input.

Comment: @yustme updated again, it doesn't have to be in document ready just script tag before closing body tag in your HTML.

Comment: In stead of initializing it on the server side, I did this: `viewModel.users = ko.observableArray();` right before the mapping line, and that worked! I did a POST but didn't receive this data on the server. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: If you initialise it server side it should make it an observable array automatically for you but the way you have done it is fine if its working for you. The posting can be tricky as you have two ways, sending it back as Ajax or a full post. Might be worth creating another question. I will check your questions tomorrow & see if I can answer it for u. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/6qsjz/4/

It's a little more like you've got. The view model element, along with your rawData should be defined before your bindings are applied.

```
var rawData = { "OtherStuff": { }, "User": {"id": "1", "name": "Bob"} }
....
viewModel = new ViewModel(rawData); 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('domElementToBind'));
```

I then showed 2 different examples of creating your objects. Check out the fiddle and follow up with any further questions.

-----EDITED-----
Here's the update so you can add more users. The key was just to make the User --> Users as an observable array and start pushing new users to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qsjz/13/

```
self.newUser = new User();
self.addUser = function() {
    self.Users.push(self.newUser);
}
```

-----EDITED-----
Oops. That's what I get for not looking both ways.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qsjz/17/

```
self.addUser = function() {
        self.Users.push(new User(self.newUser.id(), self.newUser.name()));
```

Comment: But I need to dynamically add new users. Or are you saying that every time I add a new user, I should do the bindings again?

Comment: There is something wrong with the updated jsfiddle. After adding a user, the next ones that are being added, overwrites all previous ones.